# Add specific content to a taxonomy results page

Tags: taxonomy

i use a plugin which generates a search result page where all users will be displayed who have linked to this taxonomy

the URL looks like this: `http://www.example.com/members/?skills=html`

I want now to modify this page (at the bottom i want to add text and links) how can i achieve the access to this page?

Comment: Is "members" a page, or the name of your taxonomy? What plugin have you used? You may be able to use Advanced Custom Fields plugin to do what you need.

Comment: Members is a page ( Skills is the main taxonomy and HTML is a child of skills)